# Request for tag merge: "extract-plus-grains" into "partial-mash"

Tags: support

These mean more or less the same thing. I know that some people may not be familiar with the canonical term for extract/grain hybrid brewing (partial mash brewing), but if we keep both it will confuse searches down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Extract plus grains is not the same as partial mash.  Extract plus grains refers to brewing with extract as the primary source of fermentables while steeping the specialty grains that do not need mashing to extract their flavor and sugars.  In extract plus grains brewing, no mashing is carried out.

Comment: OK, is the distinction important enough/is the extract-plus tag categorical enough to merit its continued existence, though? It seems that the "steeping" tag encompasses most of the important part of the distinction.

Comment: And not to be pedantic, but a lot of brewers consider controlled-temperature steeping to be a form of partial mashing, with the lauter tun optional.

Comment: I know of no brewers that refer to the steeping of specialty grains as partial mashing.  They are different things.  If the steep doesn't contain any base malt and in turn there is no diastatic power, it simply is not mashing.